# AWS Amplify: how to use API_KEY for test and development purpose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using amplify for my project.
I have enabled both cognito and API_KEY authorization and added following function to use instead of 'graphqlOperation' of amplify-cli

```
function graphqlOperationWithAPIKey(query, variables) {
    return {query: query, variables: variables, authMode: 'API_KEY'}
}
```

And I doing the call:

```
const response = await API.graphql(graphqlOperationWithAPIKey(mutations.createContract, {input: mockContract}))
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Failed: Object {
  "data": Object {
    "createContract": null,
  },
  "errors": Array [
    Object {
      "data": [Object],
      "errorInfo": [Object],
      "errorType": "Unauthorized",
      "locations": [Array],
      "message": "Not Authorized to access createContract on type Mutation",
      "path": [Array],
    },
  ],
}
```

Here is my schema:

```
type Contract @model {
  id: ID!    
  rental: Car @connection

  from: AWSDate!
  to: AWSDate!
  tenants: [String!]! 
  status: ContractStatus!
}
```

Can someone help me to get this work?

Comment: Seems no one uses amplify....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether is bug or not,
the below works if I add it to schema, but @aws_key doe not work (even according to doc should work as well)

```
@auth (
  rules: [
    { allow: public, provider: apiKey }
  ]
)
```